# Postgis and Postgres: How to perform a ST_Contains query with geometry array?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis

I have a boundary which is stored in a geometry array. (like {...,...,...})
My goal is to perform a ST_Contains query. I want see whether a node is inside that boundary or not.

I tried something like

```
SELECT ST_Contains(ST_Polygonize((SELECT CAST(bt.geomarray AS geometry[]) FROM boundarytable AS bt)), nodetable.geom)
```

But I always get errors like "Invalid hex character (,) encountered".
Can anybody show me the right way to do this?

Comment: I had encountered a similar error from Postgis and eventually worked out what causes it.  "Invalid hex character" is generated when a geometry type is expected but a different (non-geometry value) is supplied.  In your case it is likely a geometry[] was passed to something expecting a single geometry object.  The comma (,) separating the first two ARRAY elements is what triggered the error since geometry is represented as a long string of hex digits.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I know how to do it, I'm answering this question by myself.

We do not have to use an array. We step through each node's geom and create the polygon. We store the polygon in polygontable. (Notice: don't forget you need the polygon to be closed, so you have to add the first node as last node again in boundarytable before you perform the query. Otherwise you will get an error):

```
SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine(bt.geom)) AS geomboundary
INTO TABLE polygontable
FROM boundarytable AS bt
GROUP BY bt.dummy  -- (just a constant value to round up all bt.geom)
```

Then we can perform the ST_Contains query like

```
SELECT *, ST_Contains((SELECT geomboundary FROM polygontable), anytable.geom)
```